# How do linux users manage unmet dependencies?

Tags: packages, texlive, linux, debian, dependencies

I use Tex live on Debian. While I have no issues using the stable repository, I also want to try out the latest packages and changes that are only available on testing/sid.

Unfortunately, when I reconfigure my config file to prioritize sid then `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`, I am greeted with a long list of unmet dependency errors. When I try to manually downgrade them, the unmet dependencies themselves also have that problem, creating a recursive issue of unknown depth. I tried this on a mostly clean installation.

How do skilled users navigate this problem? Is debian not the right choice here?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092 — much easier than dealing with the packages.

Comment: I use the stable Debian package, and if I want to use a new (version of a) package then I download that package manually from CTAN, or I try it out on Overleaf. For my own work this is never needed though, this is only for answering questions here on TeX.SE. Many of these questions are about backwards incompatibility (i.e., "my document doesn't work anymore after an update") so I am usually happy to use the older versions that Debian provides :)

Comment: On Arch there's [TeX Live - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live#tllocalmgr). Not in your case.